# Way to add text from a textpad to HTML?

Tags: html, text, textpad

Okay So I know this may sound like, "What is this guy talking about" but my question is simple, is there anyway to read a .txt file and then add text from there under a < p> or < h> in terms of text so that it is easier to use for people who don't know how to code? I have team members that are writers and authors although none of them know how to code. I want to give them an easy way to redo text in our website.
Soo... anyone?

(btw I slowly am starting to like it here ^_^)

Comment: Use a CMS like Wordpress / Joomla, or add a WYSIWYG-Editor to your website. Then they will be able to manage the content without any knowledge of HTML.

Comment: @n33dle , Won't that mean that they'll have to log in? I personallay don't want to create a login menu for them because this is a website that will be shown to our sponsors :/ And our team just doesn't prefer it... But thanks anyways ^_^

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/ and load your file with server script like php or .net, whatever you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.tinymce.com

and save or load with server script like php or .net, whatever you are using

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `contenteditable="true"` parameter in a div in which you could paste or display the text such as the following example :

```
<div class='page' style="display:block;" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

And modify it with the powerful JS function (a little deprecated) `execCommand();`
Example :

```
<input type="button" value="B" onclick="document.execCommand('bold', false, '');" style="font-weight:bold"/>
<input type="button" value="I" onclick="document.execCommand('italic', false, '')" style="font-style:italic"/>
<input type="button" value="U" onclick="document.execCommand('underline', false, '')"   style="text-decoration:underline"/>
<input type="button" value="S" onclick="document.execCommand('strikeThrough', false, '')"   style="text-decoration:line-through"/>
```

That code will change the selected text, for example, if the user pushes the **B** or bold button, the selected text will be displayed in bold and in the source code of your webpage, there will be some `<b></b>` tags around the selected text.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands) a list of the function's arguments on MDC

This is an easy way of creating your own WYSIWYG HTML editor. But there are some limits...